# What are the original settings for Ayatana blacklist in Loki? 2 wifi icons

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel

I wanted to make steam icon visible on system tray, so I edited `/etc/wingpanel.d/ayatana.blacklist` and I accidentally deleted all of the blacklist names instead of only steam. So the outcome is that now I have two wifi icons on the tray and I wanna get rid of the other one. Could you please tell me what were the original names there? Thank you!

Comment: That is funny "ayatana",  While I do not know what ayatana.blacklist would do, it is a Buddhist term for for eye base, ear base, etc.  So I would imagine it is some type of blocker for things that can "interrupt".  Seems like the designers are Buddhist and Theravada too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This file is in the `elementary-default-settings` package:

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/wingpanel.d/ayatana.blacklist 
elementary-default-settings: /etc/wingpanel.d/ayatana.blacklist
```

You can download it and extract its contents

```
$ sudo apt-get --download-only --reinstall elementary-default-settings
$ dpkg --vextract /var/cache/apt/archives/elementary-default-settings*.deb /tmp
```

And now you check the contents of the file, overwrite the old one, etc. at `/tmp/etc/wingpanel.d/ayatana.blacklist`